# ResultSet and ArrayList of objects not working

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, arraylist

I am basically trying to retrieve to an `ArrayList` something i stored in my database. I iterate through ResultSet but it I get a `NullPointerException`.

```
ResultSet rs = null;
ArrayList<People> peoList=null;

try {
    rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * from people WHERE surname='"+surname+"'");
} 
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(myClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
String name, surname;
try {
    while (rs.next()) {
        name = rs.getString("name");
        surname = rs.getString("surname");

        People peo = new People(name,surname);
        peoList.add(peo);
    }
} 
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(myClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} 
return peoList;
```

When I call this function, a `NullPinterException` arises with a ton of other messages. I really don't get this. It seems that the problem  is where I put `peoList.add(peo);`. For example, if remove this and put a counter the number of iterations is ok.

Comment: Initialize `peoList`.

Comment: Several things in the code you posted are broken.  Please post the actual code, and the stacktrace of the NPE.

Comment: @rambocoder It was his first post

Comment: @rambocoder It isnt messy. I just copy-pasted a wrong "rs" which i fixed it now.

Comment: @Hnr.Snd. look at my example below. You cannot have an uninitialized `ArrayList` and then try to add something to it. It is not like `ResultSet` since your query is returning a `new` `ResultSet` when it executes... you code never initializes `peoList`. You will need to initilize it like: `List<People> peoList = new ArrayList<People>();` which will give you an empty `ArrayList`. Then you can use `.add(()` on it.

Comment: @rambocoder Thanks for your drama, that was something.

Comment: @Hnr.Snd. lol! don't worry about it... sometimes people get a little uppitty about formatting and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(rs.next())
{
    name = records.getString("name");
    surname = records.getString("surname");

    People peo= new People(name,surname);
    peoList.add(peo);

}
```

Where did `records` come from? This is not the variable name for your `ResultSet`, instead you  named it `rs`.

I think you mean to do:

```
while(rs.next())
{
    name = rs.getString("name");
    surname = rs.getString("surname");

    People peo= new People(name,surname);
    peoList.add(peo);

}
```

The exception is being thrown in your original code because `name` and `surname` are both null, as is `records` because it does not exist.

`UPDATE:`

As a comment mentioned, you appear to also not have initialized `peoList`.

You're code is a little difficult on the eyes, due to mixed style, etc.

I re-wrote some of it, but here's the gist (including a properly initialized `peoList`:

```
final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(myClass.class.getName());

ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * from people WHERE surname='"+surname+"'");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    LOG.severe("", ex);
}

String name, surname;
List<People> peoList = new ArrayList<People>();

try {
    while(rs.next()) {
        name = rs.getString("name");
        surname = rs.getString("surname");

        People peo= new People(name,surname);
        peoList.add(peo);

    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    LOG.severe("", ex);
} 

return peoList;
```

Comment: i fixed it, it was originally rs. The problem is still there.

Comment: @Hnr.Snd. check it now. (Also, I'm sure you have this inside a method, but you have not shared your method signature nor your class imports. So I'm guessing at your intentions.

Comment: Yeah , thanks, i guess. It was indeed a problem on initializing the ArrayList.Cheers